OWD on OpportunityLineItem is Read/Write and on Opportunity is Private. What access exists on Opportunity for a user?
I am looking to an organization that has the internal sharing model on OpportunityLineItem is Read/Write but the OWD on the Opportunity is Private. Does this mean all users have full access to all OpportunityLineItem records in the system but access to the associated Opportunity is restricted through role hierarchy, shares and team access only?

When the OWD is set to 'Read/Write' for Opportunity Line Items, all users can access and modify all Opportunity Line Item records regardless of sharing mechanisms like role hierarchy, team access or sharing rules.
If the OWD for Opportunity records is set to Private, only the user who created the record will be having access to the record, while other users must be granted access through role hierarchy, team access, sharing rules, or manual sharing.
Point to note here is role hierarchy, team access, sharing rules, or manual sharing is to open up access to the records and not to restrict access.
